# Cannot read property 'mockResolvedValue' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios

I'm getting an error mocking my api call

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockResolvedValue" of undefined
```

and cannot figure out why. I'm utilizing jest to test my api fetch call function.

This is my function I'm exporting:

```
//file amData.jsx

const axios = require('axios');

async function fetchAssetManagerSummary() {
  const response = await axios.get("https://www.exampleUrl.com");
  return response.data;
}

module.exports = fetchAssetManagerSummary;
```

This is my test file

```
const fetchAssetManagerSummary = require('./amData');
const axios = require('axios');
jest.mock("axios");

it("returns the object from fetch", async () => {
  axios.get.mockResolvedValue({
    data: [
      {
        userId: 1,
        id: 1,
        title: 'test'
      }
    ]
  })
  const data = await fetchAssetManagerSummary();
  console.log("data", data)
});
```

The error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: "Cannot read property 'mockResolvedValue" of undefined" is very different from what's stated in the title of the question. Please correct the title.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since you have already mocked the `axios` class, one of the ways of mocking the return value of axios.get is to do this:

```
axios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
  data: [
    {
      userId: 1,
      id: 1,
      title: 'test'
    }
  ]
});
.
.
expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Alternatively, you can spy on axios.get(), and provide a mocked return value:

```
jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce({
  data: [
    {
      userId: 1,
      id: 1,
      title: 'test'
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Why doesn't mocking as the original question does work since that is exactly what the jest documentation says to do: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules

Comment: I have the exact same issue and no idea why it is not actually working as per documentation

Comment: what the...I worked on it for half a day to make it work following the docs, and nothing. I had to change `axios.get` to `jest.fn()` without ANY reason to do it, and without the `axios.get = `. Where did you find this? It's incredible that documentation is wrong. At the moment it doesnt mock nothing btw. If I add the `axios.get = ` it says `Cannot add property get, object is not extensible`. Any ideas?