# How to mock async method fired from mounted lifecycle method?

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs

I am having trouble figuring out how to mock an async method that is called from the `mounted` lifecycle method. I am trying to mock `UsersApi.getAllUsers()`.

```
//code.vue
mounted: async function () {
  await UsersApi.getAllUsers().then(response => {
    this.options = response.data
  })
}

//code.test.js
import UsersApi from '@/api/users'
…
jest.mock('UsersApi')
UsersApi.getAllUsers.mockResolvedValue([
  {
    user_id: 123,
    first_name: 'Abc',
    last_name: 'Def'
  }
])
…
```

Output: `Cannot find module 'UsersApi' from 'code.spec.js'`

The module exists and is being used in the component. Perhaps using a mock is not appropriate for this purpose?

Another option would be to somehow suppress the mounted method, which would work because I am setting `this.options` from the test anyway.

Edit: this is where `getAllUsers` is coming from.

```
//users.js
export default {
  async getAllUsers() {
    …
  },
  async getUsers(payload) {
    …
  }
…
```

Comment: `jest.mock` takes a *path* to the module, see e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options.

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my original post with what `users.js` looks like. I think that is going to complicate things.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what's in that file, the point is that the Jest mocking method takes *the path to the module*, the same thing you'd `import whatever from "this/path/here"`, not `"whatever"` name you happen to have assigned the result to.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help.

Comment: Now I get `TypeError: _users.default.getAllUsers.mockResolvedValue is not a function`. Do you happen to have an idea for that, @jonrsharpe?

Comment: This project doesn't use TypeScript, so I guess I'll keep digging. Thanks.

Comment: This got me sorted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61627298/jest-mockresolvedvalue-is-not-a-function I ended up calling `UsersApi.getAllUsers = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue…`